# Проблема с SharedPreferences и AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-shared-preferences, android-dialog

Пытаюсь сделать настройки.
Собственно настройки сохраняю в sharedPreference.
Проблема в том, что оно странно сохраняет Boolean: зайду в настройки, всё checkbox false, перезахожу уже все true.
В чём моя ошибка?

```
/*НАСТРОЙКИ+СОХРАНЕНИЕ ИНФЫ*/
public static final String CHECK_SETTINGS = "check_settings"; //Имя файла
//Обучение
public static final String hasWathed="false"; // проверка на просмотр обучения

public static final String notifShops="true"; // уведомления магазинов
public static final String notifWebSite="true"; // уведомления сайта
```

Dialog:

```
    final CharSequence[] items = {" Получать уведомления об обновлениях сайта "," Получать уведомления об акциях магазинов "};


    sp = getSharedPreferences(CHECK_SETTINGS,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    boolean shops = sp.getBoolean(notifShops, true);
    boolean webSite = sp.getBoolean(notifWebSite, true);
    boolean[] mCheckedItems={webSite,shops};


    AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle("Настройки")
            .setMultiChoiceItems(items, mCheckedItems, new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int indexSelected, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(indexSelected==0){
                        Log.d("Settings","notifWebSite"+isChecked);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
                        e.putBoolean(notifWebSite, isChecked);
                        e.commit(); // не забудьте подтвердить изменения
                    }
                    if(indexSelected==1){
                        Log.d("Settings","notifShops"+isChecked);
                        SharedPreferences.Editor e = sp.edit();
                        e.putBoolean(notifShops, isChecked);
                        e.commit(); // не забудьте подтвердить изменения
                    }
                }
            }).setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //  Your code when user clicked on OK
                    //  You can write the code  to save the selected item here
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //  Your code when user clicked on Cancel
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            }).create();
    dialog.show();
```